How to correctly define a request_parameters during integration of AWS HTTP API Gateway with AWS SQS using CDK
I have faced with a problem while writing an integration of AWS HTTP API Gateway with SQS. I use Python + awd-cdk 2.163.1. The following code:
api_gw_integration_to_sqs = aws_apigatewayv2.CfnIntegration(
    self, 
    "SQSIntegration",
    api_id=api_gw.api_id,
    integration_type="AWS_PROXY",
    integration_subtype="SQS-SendMessage",
    payload_format_version="1.0",
    credentials_arn=api_gw_to_sqs_integration_role.role_arn,
    request_parameters={
        "QueueUrl": queue_spike_handler.queue_url,
        "MessageBody": """
        {
            "header":"${request.header.Authorization}", 
            "method":"${context.httpMethod}",
            "body": "${request.body}"
        }
        """
    }
)

fails during deployment with the error:

Resource handler returned message: "Invalid selection expression
specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid source:
{     "header":"${request.header.Authorization}",
"method":"${context.httpMethod}",   "body": "${request.body}" }
specified for destination: MessageBody]

but, it successfully deploys with the following request_parameters values:
request_parameters={
    "QueueUrl": queue_spike_handler.queue_url,
    "MessageBody": """
    {
        "header":"${request.header.Authorization}", 
        "method":"${context.httpMethod}"
    }
    """
}

or
request_parameters={
    "QueueUrl": queue_spike_handler.queue_url,
    "MessageBody": "${request.body}"
}

If anybody knows how to correct the request_parameters to get "header", "method" and "body" together in the message?

Try request.body.*
